# I want to upgrade this code to be compatible with Android 10

Tags: javascript, android

I am facing a problem in this code that makes the application not work with modern versions of Android

I want to upgrade this code to be compatible with Android 10

```
    import android.app.AlarmManager
    import android.app.PendingIntent
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver

    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent

    import android.os.Build
    import android.os.PowerManager

    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

    class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            runPower(context)
            var myService = Intent(context, SaliService::class.java)
            // context.startService(myService)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, myService);
        }


        lateinit var pm: PowerManager
        lateinit var wl: PowerManager.WakeLock
        fun runPower(context: Context) {
            this.pm = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TAG")
            //   wl.setReferenceCounted(true)
            wl.acquire()
        }

        fun stopPower() {
            if (wl != null) wl.release()
        }


        companion object {
            fun keepRunning(context: Context) {
                val time = context.getSharedPreferences("mySpinner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("SPPROG", 5)
                var myAlarm: Intent
                var recurringAlarm: PendingIntent? = null
                var alarms: AlarmManager
                myAlarm = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                //myAlarm.putExtra("project_id", project_id); //Put Extra if needed
                recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                alarms = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    val ac = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * time),
                            recurringAlarm)
                    alarms.setAlarmClock(ac, recurringAlarm)
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    alarms.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * time), recurringAlarm)
                else
                    alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * time), recurringAlarm)

            }
        }

    }
```

I am facing a problem in this code that makes the application not work with modern versions of Android

Comment: What is a modern version of Android? What version number(s)?

Comment: Versions récentes android 10 , android 9 end 8